# Merge two values from form.Model in defined CharField

Tags: django

I try to merge two values from dropdown "on the fly" to a HTML input field

model.py

```
class ProjectID(models.Model):
    project_id = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.project_name

class ProjectName(models.Model):
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.project_name

class Project(models.Model):
    combine_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    project_id = models.ForeignKey(ProjectID,
                                   related_name='p_number',
                                   on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    project_name = models.ForeignKey(ProjectName,
                                     related_name='p_name',
                                     on_delete=models.CASCADE)  

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.project_id}_{self.project_name}"
```

views.py

```
class AddProject(generic.FormView):
    template_name = 'project/project-add.html'
    form_class = ProjectAddForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('project:project-dashboard')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.dashboard, name='project-dashboard'),
    path('add/', views.AddProject.as_view(), name='project-add')
]
```

forms.py:

```
class ProjectAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['project_id', 'project_name', 'combine_name']
```

project-add.html

```
{% block main-body %}
<div class="container">
  <form method="post" class="form card p-3 mt-5">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="row align-items-start">
      <div class="col-md-4" id="option_a">
        {{ form.project_id|as_crispy_field }}
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4" id="option_b">
        {{ form.project_name|as_crispy_field }}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row align-items-center">
      <div class="col-md-8">{{ form.combine_name|as_crispy_field }}</div>
    </div>

{% endblock main-body %}
```

I try to merge `form.project_id` `form.project_name` if the dropdowns are selected and appears into the field `form.combine_name`

With jquery the result failed because I guess it's not possible to handle with templatetags

```
$('#option_a, #option_b').change(function() {
   var val = $('#option_a').val() + $('#option_b').val(),
             new_price;
   $("#new_option").text(val);
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have 2 dropdowns:

`{{ form.project_id }}` and `{{ form.project_name }}`

if the user choose both the combine of both values should be appear instantly in a seperate text fileld:

`<div class="col-md-8">{{ "form.project_id_form.project_name" }}</div>`

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need the combine_name field? It seems like all it will do is display a string of the two other fields combined. Those fields are already in the database, so it doesn't make sense to have them replicated. I would get rid of that fields altogether.

You're already creating the value dynamically with the str method. So why save it separately?

Comment: That's correct the name would be saved in database but would be nice to show combined name into the form and used as a example for further process.